# How to convert xml response to xlsx in angular 9 to download a file, getting SyntaxError: Unexpected token P in JSON at position 0

Tags: angular9

I am trying to download an excel file in angular 9. But I am getting the following error. Can anyone suggest how to convert xml to xlsx and Can verify the below code and please suggest me If I am doing anything wrong.

```
 //In service ts 
exportCandidatesCall(){  
     let headers = new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    let options = {       
       headers: headers,
        responseType: 'blob',
        observe: 'response'
        // responseType: 'arraybuffer'
    };
  return this.http.post(url,options);   
  }
  //In Component ts
 exportCandidatesList(){
    this.loginService.exportCandidatesCall().subscribe(
      (response)=>{
        if(response){
          console.log("Inside the downloaded response",response);
          this.saveAsExcelFile(response);
        }
      },
        (error) => {
         // let errorObj = JSON.parse(error);
         // if (errorObj.status === "error" ) {
              console.log("error Encountered");
         // }
      });
       
      }
       private saveAsExcelFile(result:any): void {
    const data: Blob = new Blob([result], {
      type: EXCEL_TYPE
    });
    //const data1= JSON.stringify(data);
    FileSaver.saveAs(data, 'Candidates' + '_exported'+ EXCEL_EXTENSION);
  }
```

[image: Error in console]
[image: Backend Response]

Comment: An `xlsx` file **is a* `xml` file. Also how is this related to Spring Boot?

Comment: Then I have added both response type, and error I am getting. Where I am doing wrong? Could you please suggest. Added #spring-boot because backend technology we are using spring boot

Comment: You are doing `const data1= JSON.stringify(data);` WHy? It isn't JSON you recieve it is an `xlsx` document, write it directly .

Comment: Yup mistakenly for some testing purpose wrote like that, will remove it, Actually it is not even going to the saveAsExcelFile method even, It is always going to the error logic scenario (error) => {
          let errorObj = JSON.parse(error);}

Comment: I suspect that the fact that you do `JSON.parse` in the error handling actually obfuscated your real problem, remove it and just dump the error.

Comment: Removed that and added a console statement there..!! Again going to error scenario only.  I am getting backend response with 200 status, but the saveAsExcelFile method is not at all getting called..!! Why is it happening so..??

Comment: Read my comment (which you only have done partially). I stated that the **real reason is obfuscated due to the `JSON.parse`**. So it will still fail BUT is should now give you the actual error.

Comment: After removing JSON.parse also, Even now its giving the same error please..!!

Answer (score 0):

Adding the { observe: 'body', responseType: 'blob' } options to the post call solved my problem.

so in my service the call looks as below:

```js
exportCandidatesCall() {
    let headers = new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    return this.http.post(url, headers, { observe: 'body', responseType: 'blob' });
  }
```